# Generating api keys for REST api

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, api-key

Am using phil sturgeon codeigniter REST library for my REST api, i have set up the api to use api keys in the config file and also created a table for storing the keys on my database.
I want to be able to generate a new api key for a user when the log in, to give them access to the api, and delete the key when they sign out.
Currently when i call the key controller using the PUT method to generate keys i get an error saying "the api key is invalid".
What am doing wrong?, Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your PUT method requires the person to already have an API key, try moving that method to another controller that doesn't extend the REST_Controller.